# Sails.js with Mongo can't find by _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sails.js

I'm trying to find a record on Mongo using the _id of the collection. I pass the _id, I've tried as a String and as a ObjectId, and no one works. What is odd is that using findOne it returns a completely different record, with a different _id. If I use just find, with a where, gets ALL records, it doesn't filter anything at all.

If I search using another field, then it works and gets the correct record, but I want to do it using the _id field. This is what I've tried so far:

```
MyModel.findOne({where: {_id: new    ObjectId("57926086e2a4ff010eeb8c83")}}).exec(function (err, record){
  //record completely different
});

MyModel.findOne({where: {_id:"57926086e2a4ff010eeb8c83"}}).exec(function (err, record){
  //record completely different
});

MyModel.findOne({id: new    ObjectId("57926086e2a4ff010eeb8c83")}).exec(function (err, record){
  //record completely different
});

MyModel.findOne({id:"57926086e2a4ff010eeb8c83"}).exec(function (err, record){
  //record completely different
});
```

So, what am I doing wrong?, I can't figure it out. I know (think) that I can do it using "native", but is that the only way???

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Mongoose, or are you using Waterline?

Comment: @robertklep Hummm, how can I know that? In connection.js I just configured the secion someMongodbServer, with adapter sails-mongo.

Comment: In that case, I think you're using Waterline (with which I don't have any experience). The `mongoose` tag confused me, hence the question.

Comment: Hello i am facing same problem can you please share the MyModel attributes and correct findOne query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience of our sails.js app, only your last option should work.

- When using sails.js and Waterline, you have to use `id` and NOT `_id` (your last option).
- When using MongoDB native calls via Waterline, you have to use `_id` and a `new ObjectId()` (the query param in your first option).

Comment: Yeah, this is odd but retried my last option again after your post, and it works! so don't know what was going on before that didn't worked... whatever, it works now, and with the last option :) thanks for pointing me in the right direction!